# ansible add_host set variables from file

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible's add_host to dynamically create the inventory.

Following piece of code works.

```
- add_host:
     name: hostname
     ansible_ssh_user: root
     ansible_ssh_pass: xxx
```

But what I want to achieve is ansible_ssh_user and ansible_ssh_pass to come from a file. This is what I tried.

```
- add_host:
     name: hostname
     inventory_dir: somedir
```

In the directory I have

```
$ cat somedir/host_vars/hostname
ansible_ssh_user: root
ansible_ssh_pass: xxx
```

But it doesn't work. Is this possible ? What I am doing wrong.

Comment: It's **inventory_dir**. I'd expect **inventory format**. Problem is that the **inventory_dir (and inventory_file)** is not included in **ansible_inventory_sources**, I think.